# Distinguish between dead center and live center

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Distinguish between dead center and live center in a center lathe tool when this terms are used in the context of work holding in a lathe

Comment: Workshop what.  ?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A center holds the work during rotation at the tailstock end of the lathe. A live center is mounted in bearings and rotates with the work, while a dead center does not rotate - the work rotates about it.

Live center Rotates while dead centre center does not rotate..

Comment: the dead center is also preferred for high-precision work.

Answer (score 0):

A live centre is driven by the spindle. A dead centre is on the non drive side. A revolving dead centre is also on the non drive side but has bearings so that it can revolve with the workpiece.